# Scene always rendering cube

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am not that proficient in Blender, and this has me baffled. I have it set to Cycles Render and I am using a single material that is Cycles also.
I have a scene when the view port shading is set to rendered looks like this:
[image]

but this is what is rendered:

[image]

this is my outliner:

I had to add the outliner to the first image because you need 10 reputation points. really??

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In future, if you need to add more images than SE will allow then you can upload using an external service (e.g. Imgur), add the link to your question and someone with more reputation will insert the image for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your outliner, see the 'template' object at the bottom?  You have set that object to be rendered (camera icon) but you have hidden in it in the viewport (eyeball is greyed out).  So it is appearing in your renders -- you want to hide its render visibility (by clicking the camera icon) so it is greyed out. That or just delete the entire object.

Comment: I feel like a buffoon! Thank you for the help!

Comment: @MichaelWRiemerJr don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. :-) (It will give you some reputation)